# Convert nsstring with UTF8 encoding in it?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, nsstring

I have an nsstring @"I\xe2\x80\x99m" that I want to convert to the NSString @"I'm" any idea how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSString` literal `@"I\xe2\x80\x99m"` already is `"I’m"`, there is no conversion necessary.

Demonstration:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main()
{
    NSLog(@"I\xe2\x80\x99m");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
2013-05-21 14:12:33.471 a.out[452:707] I’m
```

The escape sequences you put in your source code are interpreted in UTF-8, and the resulting UTF-8 is made into an `NSString` object.